# auto-submit form only if specific number of checkboxes had been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am new to jQuery. I am wondering if there is a way to count the number of checkboxes that have been checked and then auto-submit the form once a specific number of checkboxes had been checked. Let's say the user checks 2 checkboxes, nothing happens. The user checks the 3rd checkbox and the form submits.

```
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="this.form.submit();">
```

Comment: Yes, that sounds possible. What does your jQuery code look like?

Comment: $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length and you get the amount of checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, using no inline javascript...

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function (event) {
    var flag = $('input:checked').length > 2 ? true : false;
    if (flag) $('form').submit();
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CH9vH/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   if( $("input[type="checkbox"]:checked").length >=3) { 
        $('form').submit();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery function:

```
function SubmitIfReady() {
    if ($('.checkbox-class:checked').length == 5) { // specify the number you want
        $('#YourForm').submit();
    }
}
```

HTML (form not shown):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-class" onclick="SubmitIfReady();">
```

Or without the onclick:

JQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.checkbox-class:checked').on('change', function() {
        if ($('.checkbox-class:checked').length == 5) { // specify the number you want
            $('#YourForm').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML (form not shown):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-class">
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this...

```
$(".counted-check").click(function(e){
    var myForm = $(this).closest('form');
    if(myForm.find(".counted-check").filter(":checked").length > 3){
        myForm.submit();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HQ5N9/